# async await promises using loops in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise

Before I start, this is totally me not fully understanding the complexities of async programming in node / javascript.

I've got a multi dimensional array containing image URLs and output names. I'm trying to iterate through them, download, manipulate and output them using sharp. What I'm trying to do is capture any corrupted images that shape throws as an error, update the array and continue to do stuff with the array when the task has finished.

The problem I'm getting is my code it not waiting for the integrations to finish and therefore not continuing with the updated array.

This is the sort of code I'm using:

```
let imgArr = [['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'],['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']]

function saveImg(url, output)
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
       axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
       .then((res) => {
          sharp(res.data)
          .resize({changing size etc})
          .png({quality: 95})
          .toFile(output)
          .then(() => { resolve() })
          .catch((err) => { reject() })
    })
}

function processImg(obj){
   return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
      for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
         saveImg(obj[i][0], obj[i][1])
         .catch((err) => {
             imgArr[i][1] = 'image-not-found.png'
         })
      }
      resolve()
   })
 }

async function doStuff(){
     processImg(imgArr)
        .then(() => {
            console.log(imgArr) // this is where I'd hoped the updated array would appear
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
)

doStuff()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the various `saveImg` calls to execute in parallel or in sequence?

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. Back to learning the basics. Stack Overflow is not a coding school nor a place where somebody should rewrite your code so that it'll work. I'll give you some tips though:

1. Write an `async` function that handles an image at a time and returns axios.get (a promise)
2. Using `Array.map`, map your array through a function that transforms each item into a promise, being one call to your image handling function
3. Run that array of promises through `Promise.allSettled`. Promise.allSettled() will resolve after each promise has been rejected or resolved

Comment: @funkizer Yeah, sorry it's a little nebulous a question. I'm not after anybody rewriting my code, I just needed to get a handle on the logic. Your response is vary useful. Must admit I get really confused just settling on the basic logic. I'm going to rip this up and start again following your advice. If you post it as an answer I'll flag it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute promises in a `for` loop like that, they all start in parallel. Then you call `resolve()` immediately, before the promises actaully resolve.

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (or [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) as suggested by @funkizer in comments) to fix this:

```js
function processImg(obj){
   return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
      Promise.allSettled(obj.map((item, i) =>
         saveImg(item[0], item[1])
         .catch((err) => {
             imgArr[i][1] = 'image-not-found.png'
         })
      )).then(resolve)
   })
 }
```

But this wrapping in `new Promise` is not necessary; you can return the promise directly, as follows:

```js
function processImg(obj){
   return Promise.allSettled(obj.map((item, i) =>
      saveImg(item[0], item[1])
      .catch((err) => {
          imgArr[i][1] = 'image-not-found.png'
      })
   );
}
```

You can similarly simplify `saveImg`:

```js
function saveImg(url, output)
    return
       axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
       .then((res) =>
          sharp(res.data)
          .resize({changing size etc})
          .png({quality: 95})
          .toFile(output)
       );
}
```